# How I can hide a tab with shinyjs?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

Hi and thanks for reading me
I am working with an application that has a password layer and I would like to know how I could hide a tab item based on the person entering the application. So far it is what I have but I have not managed to make it work:

```
library(shinymanager)
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

credentials <- data.frame(
  user = c("shiny", "shiny2"), # mandatory
  password = c("111", "111"), # mandatory
  start = c("2015-04-15"), # optinal (all others)
  expire = c(NA, "2032-12-31"),
  admin = c(FALSE, TRUE),
  comment = "Simple and secure authentification mechanism 
  for single ‘Shiny’ applications.",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  moreInfo = c("someData1", "someData2"),
  level = c(2, 0)
)

if (interactive()) {
  header <- dashboardHeader()
  
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    sidebarUserPanel("User Name",
                     subtitle = a(href = "#", icon("circle", class = "text-success"), "Online"),
                     # Image file should be in www/ subdir
                     image = "userimage.png"
    ),
    sidebarSearchForm(label = "Enter a number", "searchText", "searchButton"),
    sidebarMenu(
      # Setting id makes input$tabs give the tabName of currently-selected tab
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "widgets", badgeLabel = "new",
               badgeColor = "green"),
      menuItem("Charts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
               menuSubItem("Sub-item 1", tabName = "subitem1"),
               menuSubItem("Sub-item 2", tabName = "subitem2")
      )
    )
  )
  
  body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("dashboard",
              div(p("Dashboard tab content"))
      ),
      tabItem("widgets",
              "Widgets tab content"
      ),
      tabItem("subitem1",
              "Sub-item 1 tab content"
      ),
      tabItem("subitem2",
              "Sub-item 2 tab content"
      )
    )
  )
  
  shinyApp(
    ui = secure_app(dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)),
    server = function(input, output, session) { 
      
      res_auth <- secure_server(
        check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials)
      )
      # Create reactive values including all credentials
      creds_reactive <- reactive({
        reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)
      })
      
      observe({
        req(creds_reactive())
        if (!is.null(creds_reactive()$user) %in% c("shiny") ) shinyjs::hide("widgets")
      })
      
      }
  )
}
```

Anyone have any ideas how to correct that?I can't get the tab item to hide when a certain user enters the application :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `renderMenu` instead of hiding the `menuItem` - otherwise users not allowed to access the contents can simply change the style of the UI element in their browser as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096603/shiny-start-the-app-with-hidden-tabs-with-no-delay/60229331#60229331) (I assume the contents of your `tabItem`s are also generated on the server side).

```
library(shinymanager)
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

credentials <- data.frame(
  user = c("shiny", "shiny2"), # mandatory
  password = c("111", "111"), # mandatory
  start = c("2015-04-15"), # optinal (all others)
  expire = c(NA, "2032-12-31"),
  admin = c(FALSE, TRUE),
  comment = "Simple and secure authentification mechanism 
  for single ‘Shiny’ applications.",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  moreInfo = c("someData1", "someData2"),
  level = c(2, 0)
)

header <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  sidebarUserPanel("User Name",
                   subtitle = a(href = "#", icon("circle", class = "text-success"), "Online"),
                   # Image file should be in www/ subdir
                   image = "userimage.png"
  ),
  sidebarSearchForm(label = "Enter a number", "searchText", "searchButton"),
  sidebarMenu(
    # Setting id makes input$tabs give the tabName of currently-selected tab
    id = "tabs",
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItemOutput("widgetsOutput"),
    menuItem("Charts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
             menuSubItem("Sub-item 1", tabName = "subitem1"),
             menuSubItem("Sub-item 2", tabName = "subitem2")
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem("dashboard",
            div(p("Dashboard tab content"))
    ),
    tabItem("widgets",
            "Widgets tab content"
    ),
    tabItem("subitem1",
            "Sub-item 1 tab content"
    ),
    tabItem("subitem2",
            "Sub-item 2 tab content"
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(
  ui = secure_app(dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)),
  server = function(input, output, session) { 
    
    res_auth <- secure_server(
      check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials)
    )
    # Create reactive values including all credentials
    creds_reactive <- reactive({
      reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)
    })
    
    output$widgetsOutput <- renderMenu({
      if(creds_reactive()$user == "shiny"){
        menuItem("Widgets", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "widgets", badgeLabel = "new", badgeColor = "green") 
      }
    })
    
  }
)
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot :D

Comment: Excellent solution. +1 for avoiding the hide menuitem option.